# Why only Self Start

Tags: honda

I would like to clarify that why are we getting only self starters in recent bikes why not the kickstatrters are not added.
It might put us in problem when the self starters are not working and if it is not working what is the next plan to start bike.

Please Explain me in detail so that I will be keeping my fingers crossed to purchase Honda Xblade.

Comment: The same argument ran for cars not being supplied with starting handles...

Answer (score 2):

Starter motors are extremely convenient, the technology has also become pretty light and very reliable, so having a kickstarter doesn't give you an advantage anymore. Kickstarters are also only good up to certain engine sizes, too big an engine and you need a very big person to rotate the engine.

Kickstarters will only work on traditionally carbureted engines as they don't rely on electronics to work, if you have electronic fuel injection with a dead battery a kickstarter won't be able to get you started anyway.

A traditionally carbureted engine with a dead battery can be push started in a pinch, which is really all you need as it's rare you'd need to.